# adding partition and sub partition using alter table query

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, alter-table

I want to alter an existing table and make a partition on date (column name - date_abc), I don't have particular date values, so each date value will have a separate partition and a sub partition on type(column name - type) which can be out of 3 namely, a, b and c.

Comment: Is this table non partitioned?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the table is non partitioned and I want to add a partition and sub partition

Comment: But what is the problem you are having? Also, I would be interested to understand *why* you want  to partition?

Comment: I have a lot of records in the table and I have been assigned the task of partitioning. The table has lakhs of records. I just need the query. Hope you can understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [interval partitioning](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1#interval_partitioning). It is solution for your requirement.

Interval partitioning is an enhancement to range partitioning in Oracle 11g and interval partitioning automatically creates time-based partitions (DAY, MONTH, YEAR etc) as new data is added

Here is link for example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE

Ofcourse you can combine interval partition with list based sub partition. Here is an example from asktom forum.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5257352600346172725

Comment: I don't want to separate values on date range. I want a particular date to be a partition. E.g. 01-Jan-2017 has 4 lakh records, so I want them to be in a single partition. like wise for others

Comment: In case of `range partition` you will have to manually create a partition for each date. In case of `interval partition` system will automatically create a separate partition for each date. All you have to do is to specify `interval(numtodsinterval(1, 'DAY'))` while redefining table.